# Dimension of a subgroup of a solenoid with measure zero

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a connected compact finite-dimensional abelian group (also called a solenoid). If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with Haar measure $0$, can we say something about the connectedness or the dimension of $H$?

Answer (score 0):

You can't say anything about the connectedness of $H$. The torus $S^1\times S^1$ is a finite dimensional compact abelian group, both $C_p\times\{1\}$ (I denote by $C_p$ the group of roots of unity of degree $p$) and $S^1\times \{1\}$ are subgroups of $S^1\times S^1$ of measure zero, one is connected and the other one is discrete (hence totally disconnected).